# Android Could not find resource for multidex-1.0.3.pom

Tags: android, gradle

when I try to run application on my phone, in AndroidStudio Gradle try to solve `multidex-1.0.3.pom` into my project by I get this error:

```
{

    "errors": [
        {
            "status": 404,
            "message": "Could not find resource"
        }
    ]

}
```

and cause of fail to building project,

my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.3-2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to move up the google maven above the jcenter in allProjects repository like below:

```
allprojects {
   repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
        }
        jcenter()

   }
}
```